# Emacs configure lsp-mode / lsp-ui

Tags: javascript, lsp-mode, lsp-ui

I work mainly with javascript and typescript. And I have enabled lsp-mode  in Doom Emacs. But I am not very happy about the descriptions and information shown to me on hover. It is not very useful and its spread out in opposite corners of the window.

take this example when I hover over `.get()` - emacs vs vscode.
[image: on hover in emacs]
[image: on hover vscode]

VSCode show me that the parameters is of type `<P ResBody, ReqBody>` whereas Emacs give me `<ParamsDictionary, any, any>`

In Emacs I have "to go definition" to get that more precise/accurate information. 
[image]

I don't really understand what controls this behaviour, lsp-ui or something else? If someone have some good information or link on how to make this in my eyes slight more useful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the same problem with `eglot`?

Comment: ```lsp-ui``` is configured in ```~/.emacs.d/modules/tools/lsp/config.el``` and in ```use-package! lsp-ui``` function, under ```:config``` section, it is stated: ```lsp-ui-doc-enable nil``` and is followed by some explanations - seems to be a small bug around.

Comment: @Stefan I have not tried with eglot. I have enough problems with the packages as is :D